# How to run tesseract from command prompt in windows xp?

Tags: ocr, command-prompt, tesseract, windows-xp-sp3

I have installed the tesseract OCR engine in my windows xp sp3 desktop.I am now trying to running the engine from command prompt as advised here https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe

The command they have given is 
tesseract imagename outputbase [-l lang] [-psm pagesegmode] [configfile...]

tesseract myscan.png out

I am trying to read a file named CSE_Curriculum so my command looks like this

tesseract CSE_Curriculum.pdf out

But it gives me the following error

cannot open file : CSE_Curriculum.pdf

My installer includes the train data, so what is the problem? What should be the appropriate command lines and where I should put my file.I have tested it keeping it in documents, desktop as well as documents and settings.

Comment: Which image formats does it support?

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract does not support reading PDF out of the box. You'll need to convert it to a supported image format first.